# Set column length in pyspark dataframe when a custom schema is used

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Pyspark:

Is it possible to set/change the column length of a spark dataframe when writing the DF to a jdbc target ?

For e.g i have a source with no header and want to add these columns

```
Full Name, age, City, State, Address
```

I read the source with a custom schema with column name and datatype to create the DF.
I want to limit age to 3 digit and Address to 100 chars.
Is it possible to provide fixed length to the columns when DF is created ?